# RegEx help to replace partial url (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, url, replace

I have text like (similar) to this throughout my file:

```
<td>
[<a href="/abc123/handouts/files/directory1/somename.pdf" target="_blank">Slides</a> ]  [ [<a href="/abc123/handouts/files/directory2/somename2.pdf" target="_blank">Handout</a> ]</td>

<td>
[<a href="/abc123/handouts/files/directory3/somename343.pdf" target="_blank">Slides</a> ]  [ <a href="/abc123/handouts/files/directory5/somename2324.pdf" target="_blank">Handout</a> ]
</td>
```

Everything after the "/abc123/handouts/files/" text will be different (directory and .pdf name)

I cant seem to fully figure out how to replace JUST the "directory3/somename343.pdf" portion with say: "XXXXXXX"

my attempts have either produced nothing, or have removed the rest of the line after the first match?

my attempt:

Search For:

```
<a href="/abc123/handouts/files/.*."
```

Replace with:

```
<a href="/abc123/handouts/files/xxxxxxx"
```

leaves me with this:

```
[ <a href="/abc123/handouts/files/xxxxxxx">Handout</a> ]
```

completely removing the first line (link)?

What am I doing wrong?  and more so, how is it done correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using? Is `sed` ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is greedy (the `*` without a `?`) so it matches everything, even after the .pdf. To make it non-greedy:

```
<a href="\/abc123\/handouts\/files\/.*?"
```

Will match everything inside the quotes, but not including the final quote.
Then replace with:

```
<a href="/abc123/handouts/files/xxxxxxx"
```

Here's regex101 for you to see: https://regex101.com/r/oY8pI8/2

Comment: answer accepted.

Thanks direct and to the point.  (good to know about the needed ? in my attempt!)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript version for string replacement.

```js
var re = /"(\/abc123\/handouts\/files\/)((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*\/)*[a-zA-Z]*.[A-ZA-z]{3,4})"/;
var str = '"/abc123/handouts/files/directory1/somename.pdf"';
var newstr = str.replace(re, '"$1XXXXX"');
alert(newstr);
```

In essence the above code is broken up into 3 parts.
Initial grab

```
"(/abc123/handouts/files/)
```

Non capturing group to find further folders

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*\/)*
```

Specific document format

```
[a-zA-Z]*.[A-ZA-z]{3,4}
```

Noting that the final folder and document format are wrapped together within a group

```
((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*\/)*[a-zA-Z]*.[A-ZA-z]{3,4})
```

Captures will thus be ordered as follows
0 - Entire match
1 - Initial folder match
2 - Trailing directory and path match

Comment: aarrrgh..  sorry guys. I should have known better to add Notepad++ in the title (sorry).

I just discovered regex101.com today, but I didnt really get how it worked?  (like how you replace things?)..

@remus - I'll give your suggestion a try.. thanks!